# How fast is the NXT blockchain growing in 2014?

Tags: blockchain, nxt

Is there a place that where I can find out how fast the NXT blockchian is growing? I'm curious because its this year (2014) where a bunch of nxt features came into the scene and was wondering how one would monitor the growth size of the blockchain from month to month. This can give me a good idea of nxt usage and adoption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NXT blockchain size is now around 1.5GB in 18 month that's roughly 83MB increase per month.